# Laravel Class Not Found FatalErrorException

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Here is the error I see.

> Class 'A\B\C\D\F\ETypeRequiredException' not found

**What I Tried**

- composer dump
- composer dump-autoload & composer dump-autoload -o
- Moved the class to A\B\C\D\R and voala! It is working.
- Moved back and again, not working.

**Code Snippets**

The page I see the error:

```
<?php namespace A\B\C\D\R;

use A\B\C\D\EInterface;
use A\B\C\D\F\ETypeRequiredException;

class E implements EInterface
    protected function foo()
    {
        if(empty($this->bar)) { throw new ETypeRequiredException("Bar is undefined."); }
    }
```

The Page That Never Loaded

```
<?php namespace A\B\C\D\F;

class ETypeRequiredException extends \UnexpectedValueException {}
```

Comment: Are you using psr-0 or classmap to resolve those namespaces?

Comment: psr-0. Using "A": "app"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using psr-0 to resolve your namespaces:

```
"psr-0": {
    "X": "app"
}
```

You should be aware that it will use you path structure, so

```
ETypeRequiredException
```

Should be put in

```
app/A/B/C/D/F/ETypeRequiredException.php
```

Comment: Sorry I fixed it. "A": "app"*

Comment: Interface is running. My my facade is working. I can call the facade from controller but just that exception.

Comment: OMG I see now. Can't I use exceptions.php to declare all my exception classes?

Comment: You can, as long as you namespace all the things.